# self presentModalViewController Not working on ViewDidLoad?

Tags: xcode

Im writing an iPhone app and I need it to check something with an if statement in ViewDidLoad, if it sees that there is nothing in an NSString that I have it calls a method. It works fine, I can NSLog through the method that was called and everything but I cant do this:

    testing * test = [[testing alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserSetupViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:test animated:NO];

Does anyone have any idea why? I can do it with an IBAction just fine. Whats going on?
I have tried the above code in the view did loads if statement but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in viewDidAppear instead. Your view is probably not even visible yet.

Comment: Terrific. Thanks very much! :D